# How to use erubis with mamp

Tags: ruby, mamp, erubis

i found out erubis, the "fast, secure, and very extensible implementation of eRuby",
now after install through gem install erubis, my question is how to run in on mac?
especially on mamp?

i been no luck finding answer on google so anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure Apache tu run rhtml files, have a look here:

http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/web.html